# Historical English word for raw meat

Tags: single-word-requests, old-english, food, animals

Are there any words for raw meat?

This can mean raw fermented meat, raw cultured meat, raw fresh meat, raw high meat, raw spoiled meat.

And can include specific types of meat, such as poultry, pork, bacon, beef, fish, etc.

I'd like to go back as far as possible, to Old English/Anglish, and even Germanic origins if possible. As an aside, I am curious whether the Germanic peoples were consuming raw meats going back to antiquity.

The only word that I can think of is *carrion*.

Comment: Except in the generally medieval and early modern sense of "meat" meaning "food" as in the expression "it was meat and drink to him" where even bread, vegetables and fruit could be called "meat" fish would not be considered meat. The flesh of mammals, birds an even reptiles is called meat, but not that of fish.

Comment: Carrion is not food- unless you’re a vulture.  As far as I know all the English terms for forms of raw meat are loan words from other languages: carpaccio, tartare, sushi, sashimi etc

Comment: @BoldBen If meat meant food, what words did they use for flesh based foods?

Comment: @Jim The bible puts a prohibition on eating carrion in Genesis ch.9 -- that leads me to believe that for many humans, Carrion was probably seen as food.

Comment: And starving people eat garbage out of trash bins. It doesn’t make it food.  Why do you think the Bible contains that admonition?  Because it’s not a good thing to do.

Comment: @Akiva They referred to it as 'flesh'. I think that it would have included fish as well but I'm not too sure.. Of course English is unusual in having differnt names for the animal and the meat in many cases (cow/beef, pig/pork, sheep/mutton and deer/venison). This is said to derive from the fact that the animals were looked after by Alnglo-Saxon herders but eaten primarily by Norman noblemen.

Comment: @Jim https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fmedia.giphy.com%2Fmedia%2FhvLcArkX4ALJu%2Fgiphy.gif&f=1&nofb=1

Comment: Does it have to be a word that modern speakers will recognize, as they will **flesh**?

Comment: @TimR No, it does not.

Answer (score 5):

'flesh' is a reasonable choice (as BoldBen put in a comment above.)

As to the 'does it include fish' I'd say no, hence Mercutio's line in Romeo and Juliet "O flesh, how thou art fishified"... ( around line 40 in the link [Folger library: Romeo and Juliet act 2 scene 4](https://www.folger.edu/explore/shakespeares-works/romeo-and-juliet/read/2/4))

Comment: I'm not sure that "flesh" alone works, since I see historical examples that use "raw flesh", such as Chaucer's "Thise shrewes ne holden hem nat apayed of roosted flessh and sode flessh..but they wole haue raw flessh of folkes wyues and hir doghtres."

Comment: +1 I had to upvote this just for the word *fishified* :D

Answer (score 4):

Middle English **braun, braon, brawun (among other spellings)** which means "flesh, meat" and survives in ModE "brawn".  *Brawn* would probably do nicely in that it is recognizable and there's nothing delicate about the notion of tearing into some brawn.

If it doesn't have to be a word modern English speakers would recognize, there is Middle-English  **lir, lere** which can mean (edible) "meat", from Old English **lira**, "brawn, muscle".

Not suggesting that either of these words meant "meat to be eaten raw"; but neither does the meaning entail being roasted or cooked.

Both have Germanic cognates.

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to go back as far as possible, to Old English/Anglish, and even Germanic origins if possible.

Then, one can find it in the ultimate origin of the word *raw* itself which is a word inherited from Germanic. The ultimate origin is the PIE root **kreue-* meaning "raw flesh". *[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/raw#English)* provides the etymological path of *raw* as below:

> From Middle English *rawe, raw, rau*, from Old English *hrēaw* (“raw, uncooked”), from Proto-West Germanic **hrau*, from Proto-Germanic **hrawaz, *hrēwaz* (“raw”), from Proto-Indo-European **krewh₂-* (“raw meat, fresh blood”).

*[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*kreue-)* lists the English words ultimately from the PIE root **kreue-* and also lists the words in other languages from this PIE root where some of them mean or suggest "raw flesh":

> **kreuə-*, Proto-Indo-European root meaning "raw flesh."
>
> It forms all or part of:
>
> creatine; creosote; crude; cruel; ecru; pancreas; raw; recrudesce; recrudescence.
>
> It is the hypothetical source of/evidence for its existence is provided by: Sanskrit *kravis-* "raw flesh," *krura-* "raw, bloody;" Greek *kreas* "flesh;" Latin *crudus* "bloody, raw; cruel," cruor "thick blood;" Old Irish *cru* "gore, blood," Middle Irish *cruaid* "hardy, harsh, stern;" Old Church Slavonic *kry* "blood;" Old Prussian *krawian*, Lithuanian *kraūjas* "blood;" Old English *hreaw* "raw," *hrot* "thick fluid, serum."

If you don't want to go back further than Old English, there is the Old English word *hrēaw* and it is the oldest form of the modern English word *raw* in the history of English. It was mainly used as an adjective in Old English also but *OED* lists a noun sense of *raw* (which has an isolated usage now) with the Old English origin *hreaw* (which might have been used for raw meat):

> A raw person, article, product, etc.; in later use spec. (in plural) (a) raw sugar; (b) raw oysters.
> In Old English in the genitive singular.
>
> **OE**
> Ne ne eton ge of ðam nan ðing hreawes [*OE Laud MS.* hreowes]. 
> <sub>Old English Hexateuch: Exodus (Claudius MS.) xii. 9</sub>
>
> <sub>Oxford English Dictionary, s.v. “raw, n.¹, sense 1.a”, July 2023. https://doi.org/10.1093/OED/4810180180</sub>

*[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hr%C3%A6w#Old_English)* lists the Old English *hræw* also as an alternative form of *hrēaw*. It is listed as a noun meaning:

> corpse, carrion 
> Synonyms: *ǣs* (“carrion”), *līċ* (“corpse”), *wæl* (“(slain) corpse”)

Thus, Old English *ǣs* (n.) is another candidate and the definitions listed in *[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A6s#Old_English)* are:

> 1. food, meat
> 2. carrion, dead carcass